# Sign into Chrome from getAuthToken screen happens even with user already signed in

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome App where I am checking the user´s email with the `identity` permission:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo){
    console.log(userInfo.email);
});
```

It works fine. However, only when the user is signed into Chrome with their Google profile.

It might happen that the user is not logged in, so before the `getProfileUserInfo` call, I am doing a `getAuthToken` with the interactive mode set to true, in order to force a login page:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
     });
```

However, after the user logs in correctly and a Chrome Profile is set up, when they run the application next time, they get the popup again, despite they are already signed in.

My attempt was to wrap the token call with another identical call but with the interactive mode set to false, so if it fails, it triggers the call with the interactive mode set to true.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    'interactive': false
}, function (token) {

    if (!token) {
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
            'interactive': true
        }, function (token) {});

    }

});
```

This is still causing the same issue (user logs in correctly, but next time they run the app, they get the sign in screen again).

I know that `getProfileUserInfo` works fine without the `getAuthToken`, as long as the user is already signed in, but I would like a system to prompt the ones that are not.

How can I get the sign in screen only once?

Comment: And why can't you detect the failure in `getProfileUserInfo` and _then_ call `getAuthToken`?

Comment: are you sure that your api key was created using the  published chrome app id?

Comment: The api key and the app id are under control (otherwise an error displays in the console) Actually, @Xen ´s suggestion is pretty good: I am trying to do it the other way around, but your way could work best. I will attempt it...

Answer (score 0):

for future people: i fixed the problem by activating the sync of the gmail acc. Appareantly the "local" sign in acc is not the same acc that is "online acc identify is searching".

Further you can read this post
[chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo() returns empty id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898503/chrome-identity-getprofileuserinfo-returns-empty-id)

## for google

chrome.identify.auth2 the user is not sign in error. chrome.identify.auth2 everytime.

Comment: by having activated the sync acc, the chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo() will return a id and email, while having sync deactivated returns a "not logged in user a.ka empty id"