# chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo() returns empty id

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, identity

I don't know if this is a development only issue, because I've not published my extension. **getProfileUserInfo() returns {email:"",id:""}.** It doesn't matter if I'm logged into chrome or not.

Here is my permissions from my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "identity", //determines authorization status
    //"notifications",
    "tabs",
    "offscreenTabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
],
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo((userInfo) => {
    debugger;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need `identity.email` permission. See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo)

Comment: It should only be blank if an account is not signed in.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I confirmed it is the same problem and solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation the id should always be available when the user is logged in. This doesn't seem to be the case for some reason. Adding the "identity.email" permission does fix the missing id issue.

As of M41+ the documentation indicates that to get id that email permission is required.

Comment: chrome sync needs to be turned on for this API to work

Comment: @PhaneendraCharyuluKanduri How do you turn on chrome sync?